# Database selector

Tags: linux, database, bash, shell

I am working on a database service for Linux Ubuntu. I have an error in my GUI terminal menu program for connecting to databases.

Code:

```
 echo -n "Database Name > "
 read character
 i=0
 while [ $i != -1 ]; do
  line=awk NR==$i /etc/kittydb/databases.txt
  if [ $character = $line ]; then
   echo "Done"
   break
  else
  $i+1;
  fi
 done
```

Output:

```
/usr/local/bin/kittydb: 114: [: =: argument expected
/usr/local/bin/kittydb: 118: /usr/local/bin/kittydb: 0+1: not found
/usr/local/bin/kittydb: 113: /usr/local/bin/kittydb: /etc/kittydb/databases.txt: Permission denied
```

How can I fix the errors above?

Comment: What you mean by *not working*? What you expect your code to do? What it is doing right now? Please read [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: Please take a look: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: A little more concise, no personal reference.
You may want to show reasonable effort prior asking the Stack Overflow community to help solve the issues at hand.

Comment: If you want a better reception to your questions in the future, consider finding the core question about language semantics underlying your question, and building a reproducer that focuses specifically on that one item, as opposed to your use case. StackOverflow's purpose is to build a reusable knowledge base; building questions meaningful to more than only yourself is thus necessary for the questions you ask to be maximally helpful towards that goal. See also http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and http://sscce.org/.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to check if the database name in a file and display "Done" if found only for the first occurrence of the match use:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo -n "Database Name > "
read character
awk -v cha=$character '$0 == cha {print "Done";exit;}' /etc/kittydb/databases.txt
```

you don't need a `for` loop to iterate through a file. `awk` will do that.

Comment: `-v cha="$character"` might be a bit safer; `IFS= read -r character`, likewise.

Comment: ...also, if we're getting really pedantic, POSIX doesn't specify what output of `echo` looks like when passed `-n`; thus, `printf '%s' 'Database Name >'` is a bit safer. (See http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/utilities/echo.html)